# Convert string to Tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I have to read data from file and convert it to a Tuple. Sample data is

```
(List(-28.92706839930671, 70.0055196968918, 97.18634024152067, -0.8977639173269137, -20.95631222378548),List(-2.1642508141664965, -49.26719368168469, -77.6449011447281, -92.11164347698504, 39.31785782242422),8.387308243500957E10,0.95,0.1)
```

I am using following code to read data from file.

```
val dataSource = Source.fromFile("/path/3.txt")
val lines = dataSource.getLines()
for (line <- lines) {
  line 
}
```

How can I convert string **line** to Tuple of  **( List[Double] , List[Double] , Double , Double , Double )** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of your input is *exactly* like the sample in the question with no possibility of invalid input, one solution is to use the following in the for loop:

```
val ls = line.replaceAll("\\(", "")
  .replaceAll("\\)","")
  .replaceAll("List", "")
  .split(",")
(ls.slice(0,5).map(_.toDouble).toList, ls.slice(5,10).map(_.toDouble).toList,
  ls(10).toDouble, ls(11).toDouble, ls(12).toDouble)
```

Result:

```
(List[Double], List[Double], Double, Double, Double) = (List(-28.92706839930671, 70.0055196968918, 97.18634024152067, -0.8977639173269137, -20.95631222378548),List(-2.1642508141664965, -49.26719368168469, -77.6449011447281, -92.11164347698504, 39.31785782242422),8.387308243500957E10,0.95,0.1)
```

Comment: line contains List[Double] , List[Double] , Double , Double , Double. Yours code is throwing error.

Comment: So you want to filter out the `List`s and the parens out of the string then?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need this in such a way let store result of converting string to tuple in result object. result._1 and result._2 should return List[Double], result._3,result._4,result._5 should return Double

Comment: @Asif , Please check the edit. It doesn't throw an error on my side btw. The idea is to just to get a list of numbers and then *split* and *slice* that list

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. One more thing. Currently length of both lists is 5. What if length of lists increases? In each case length of both lists will remain same.

Comment: @Asif , if this completely solves your problem, please accept the answer. For varying length list, you need to explain the requirements, like what is minimum or maximum length the lists can have? What happens to the single members in the end, etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223306/discussion-between-asif-and-jrook).